# How would I find the location of the intersecting point?

Tags: linear-algebra

How would I find the location of the intersecting point if starting point and midpoint could be anywhere below the line. The starting point will always be below the midpoint. What would the formula to find this be?

The image is below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmhYl.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the midpoint as just another point on the line. With two points, you know all you need to know about the line. If you wanted, you could use middle-school algebra skills by finding the slope between the two points and finding the equation for the line through one of the points. Then see when it hits the required height.